# What is the differnce between `void *ptr[N](int)` and `void (*ptr)[N](int)` in c?

Tags: c, function, pointers, operator-precedence

Let's say I have
`void (*ptr[3])(int)`
and
`void (*ptr)[3](int)`

The first one works as expected.
But the second one throws an error.

I tried both, but could not figure out the problem.
The error reads:

> "..error: declaration of ‘ptr’ as array of functions    void
> (*ptr)3;"

Comment: Note that the `void *ptr[N](int)` of the question title is different from both the declarations at the beginning of the question body.  It's an array of function (int) returning pointer-to-void.  (Which is still not allowed.)  What are you actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: @JohnBollinger Good catch. I didn't even notice that there's a different declaration in the title.

Answer (score 5):

`void (*ptr)[3](int)` is same same as declaring `ptr` to be a pointer to an array of functions, which isn't allowed. You can't have arrays of functions.

```c
typedef void(functype)(int);
functype ptr[3];              // error
```

What you need is most probably an array of function *pointers*, which is what your working declaration, `void (*ptr[3])(int)`, creates.

```c
typedef void(functype)(int);
functype* ptr[3];
//      ^
```

Usage example:

```c
void a(int x) {}
void b(int x) {}
void c(int x) {}

int main(void) {
    typedef void(functype)(int);

    functype* ptr[3] = {a,b,c};
}
```

Comment: You're probably right that they want an array of function pointers, but I guess it's possible that they want a function that returns a pointer to an array.

Comment: @JohnBollinger True. I've clarified what I'm actually answering a bit to not cause too much confusion in case I guessed wrong.

Comment: `void (*ptr)[3](int)` is "a pointer to array of functions",  not "array of functions"

Comment: consider `typeof(void(int))* ptr[3];`

Comment: @tstanisl Thanks, updated. `typeof` is also a nice C23 addition but I'll stick with an old-school `typedef` for now.

Comment: @tstanisl That _really_ doesn't add any to readability at all, quite the contrary. So the _only_ thing achieved with that syntax is breaking backwards-compatibility.

Comment: @Lundin, I dare not to agree with you, but it is a matter of taste.

Answer (score 2):

Whoever came up with the syntax for pointers to function or array didn't have much of a rationale behind it - most likely it just happened by chance. There's some rules here:

- Functions don't really exist in expressions, only function pointers do. C17 6.3.2.1 §4:

  > A *function designator* is an expression that has function type. Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, or the unary `&` operator, a function designator with type "function returning type" is converted to an expression that has type "pointer to function returning type".
- Declaration/initialization is "harmonized" with operator precedence in expressions. Meaning that `int*p[3]` always means "array of 3 int pointers" and never "pointer to array of 3 int", just as the expression `*p[3]` always means "access the 4th element and then de-reference".

For the above reasons compilers may have a hard time producing sensible diagnostics when faced with illegal syntax. In this case the error `int p [3] (void);` and the error  `int (*p) [3] (void);` give the same diagnostic message in both gcc and clang, some flavour of "declaration of 'p' as array of functions". Though it isn't obvious how the latter would ever be considered an "array of functions". In fact the former is an array of functions and the latter is a pointer to an array of functions - neither is allowed.

As we can tell, pretty much *nobody* understands this mess, including those who wrote the compiler diagnostics for gcc and clang. The few who pretend they do are those willing to spend ridiculous amounts of time parsing needlessly obscure expressions following "clockwise spirals" until their eyes look like clockwise spirals... don't do that.

**The #1 rule here is to *always* use typedef when working with function pointers, no exceptions.**

Here is a little FAQ:

```c
int ptr1 (void);           // OK. Function
int (ptr2) (void);         // Weird but OK. Still a function
int ptr3 [3] (void);       // Invalid declaration - array of functions
int (*ptr4) (void);        // OK. Pointer to function
int (*ptr5 [3]) (void);    // OK. Array of pointers to functions
int (*ptr6) [3] (void);    // Invalid declaration - pointer to array of functions
int ((*(*ptr4)(void))[3]); // Madness, pointer to a function returning a pointer to array of 3 int
```

Strongly recommended practices:

```c
typedef int func_t (void);   // function type
func_t* func;                // function pointer
func_t* func[3];             // array of function pointers
func_t* const func = f;      // read-only function pointer, can't be reassigned
func_t* const func[3] =      // read-only array of function pointers, can't be reassigned
{ ... };
```

Comment: _"always use typedef when working with function pointers"_ - This makes me feel a little less stooopid since I do that because I think they often are really messy to decipher :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo You can toss an expression like `int ((*(*ptr4)(void))[3]);` at a group of very experienced programmers and it _will_ take them considerable time to parse it, if they even manage at all - I wouldn't really expect them to since reading C code shouldn't be a f-in' Mensa test. I had to double-check that one with a compiler before posting it here myself. And then obviously if even the veteran programmers struggle with it, beginner to intermediate programmers don't stand a chance. Whereas the style at the end of this answer should be easily understood even by beginners.